# No Duplication values

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is I want insert values without duplicating values.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SD_Sproc_Result]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
        @employeeid varchar(100),
        @providercode varchar(100)

AS
BEGIN

        Insert into TR_employeesprovidercode (employeeid, providercode) values
        (@employeeid, @providercode)

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TR_employeesprovidercode
                   WHERE employeeid = @employeeid 
                   AND providercode = @providercode)
 BEGIN
      Insert into TR_employeesprovidercode (employeeid, providercode) 
      values (@employeeid, @providercode)
 END
```

Alternatively, you could create a unique constraint on the table containing the two columns employeeid and providercode.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
ADD UNIQUE (employeeid, providercode);
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SD_Sproc_Result, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some fields as `unique` and use `INSERT IGNORE...`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Read about the `IGNORE` keyword.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Read about unique-keys.